# REGEX creating HIVE EXTERNAL TABLE - issue no results during SELECT

Tags: regex, hive

I have the following sample data:

```
"HD",003498,"20160913:17:04:10","D3ZYE",1
"EH","XXX-1985977-1",1,"01","20151215","20151215","20151229","20151215","2304",,,"36-126481000",1340.74,61808.00,1126.62,0.00,214.12,0.00,0.00,0.00,"30","20151229","00653845",,,"PARTS","001","ABI","20151215","Y","Y","N","36-126481000",
```

I created a input.regex to get the fields defined since the file has numerous record type (signified by the first-2 character in the record)

Here is the statement that I have :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE EntryHeaderTable
(RecordType STRING
,EntryNumber STRING
,VersionNumber STRING
,EntryType STRING
,ImportDate STRING
,EntryDate STRING
,EntrySummaryDate STRING
,ForeignExportDate STRING
,PortCode STRING
,MasterBillofLading STRING
,ImporterofRecord STRING
,ImporterofRecord2 STRING
,TotalDue STRING
,EnteredValue STRING
,Duty STRING
,HarborMaintenanceFee STRING
,MerchandiseProcessingFee STRING
,DeferredTax STRING
,Tax STRING
,AD_CVD STRING
,ModeofTransportation STRING
,ACHPaymentDate STRING
,BrokerReferenceNumber STRING
,ReconciliationFlagforNAFTA STRING
,ReconciliationFlagforOther STRING
,CommodityDescriptionCode STRING
,SuretyCode STRING
,VersionReasonCode STRING
,VersionDate STRING
,ABIIndicator STRING
,PaperlessIndicator STRING
,IDProceduresFlag STRING
,UltimateConsignee STRING
,Filler STRING
)
    row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
    with serdeproperties ("input.regex" = "(\EH\")(\,?.*)")
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/users/username/co/file'
;
```

it is giving me a message that it does not match the groups :

```
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: Number of matching groups doesn't match the number of columns
```

But I counted the columns in the record definition and it matches the total number of groups produced by the regex.

The regex recognizes the record using regextesters like txt2re or regeExr

UPDATE: 
I also tried to do the following definition to symbolize that there is 33 occurrences of the 2nd field

with serdeproperties ("input.regex" = "(\EH\"){1,33}(\,?.*)")

The only reason that I did not do CSV format for this, since I want to provide the record type as a variable field that changes for each of the record type

Comment: **(1)** Your regex contains only 2 groups (2 patterns surrounded by brackets) and you have many more columns than that **(2)** I see no reason to use RegexSerDe here. Use OpenCSVSerde as I demonstrated in my answer to your original question

Comment: @Dudu.. I actually have 34 columns in the csv.. so the 2nd group is 33 times for this record type.. I updated the main thread and shown you the edits and let me know .. Also since I need to define only the EH record types

Comment: The is no how RegexSerDe works. Every expression in brackets in mapped to a  single column. And once again, no need for RegexSerDe here.

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz ... can you demonstrate how you would load this file to two separate tables using the OpenCSVSerde.. I did not see where I can put a filter to load one table with just HD record types and another table with just the EH Hope you can assist